# Switching a template based on value in Iron Router

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to create a `product` editor page in my application. The product data is completely variable, however it is structured like so:

```
{
    "_id" : "543e759ff08da702009542d2",
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "binding" : "title",
            "type" : "text",
            "_id" : "543e759ff08da702009542d8",
            "data" : "A TEST Product Title"
        }, 
        {
            "binding" : "description",
            "type" : "multiLineText",
            "_id" : "543e759ff08da702009542d7",
            "data" : "Oooo... Simply delicious text that describes the product in detail"
        }, 
        {
            "binding" : "price",
            "type" : "currency",
            "_id" : "543e759ff08da702009542d6",
            "data" : "£2.25"
        }, 
        {
            "binding" : "image",
            "type" : "image",
            "_id" : "543e759ff08da702009542d5",
            "data" : "http://www.google.com/image.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far on the page I have an `{{#each fields}}` block within a form.

What I'd like to do is have separate "textEditor", "currencyEditor", etc. templates for each type of field that may need to be edited, keeping all the logic nicely separated.

How do I best go about injecting the relevant template into the view?

A **very** crude way would be something like:

```
{{#each fields}}
  {{#if typeIs 'text'}}
    {{>textEditor}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if typeIs 'currency'}}
    {{>currencyEditor}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Template.dynamic`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic):

```html
<template name="main">
    {{#each fields}}
        {{> Template.dynamic template=getTemplateName}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.main.helpers({
    getTemplateName: function(){
        return this.type+"Editor"
    }
})
```

---

**Regarding your new question from the comment**: the proposed solution below isn't good enough? You want one single save event?

```html
<template name="textEditor">
    <form>
        <input type="text" value="{{data}}">
    </form>
</template>
```

```js
Template.textEditor.events({
    'submit form': function(){
        event.preventDefault()
        // Save text type.
    }
})
```

```html
<template name="multiLineTextEditor">
    <form>
        <textarea>{{data}}</textarea>
    </form>
</template>
```

```js
Template.textEditor.events({
    'submit form': function(){
        event.preventDefault()
        // Save multi line text type.
    }
})
```

Comment: Woah. I didn't even know you could do that. Have my upvote and my thanks!

Comment: Sorry to extend my question Peppe, but if I do it in the way you describe, how the hell am I supposed to wire up the "Save" button at the end of the form? Only each "editor" template knows how best to save it's own data, but I want the save done in a single update when the user presses save... Any ideas?

Comment: @Siyfion, the solution in my updated answer isn't good enough?

Comment: That is a perfect answer, but my use-case is slightly different. All my "editors" are in a single form, so the submit is triggered in the parent template of all the editors. Although I guess they *may* still be able to handle the `submit form` event??

Comment: @Siyfion, the editor templates can't listen on the submit event (in a Meteor way) if the form is in their parent template, but the parent template can access the form fields in the editor templates.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, "Dynamic Templates" is what I was looking for, and sure enough, they're already available.

Here's a blog post going over them: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/